# SpaCy - ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2) (1,5)

Tags: python, pytorch, spacy, multiclass-classification

In relation to the previous post on stackoverflow
[Model() got multiple values for argument 'nr_class' - SpaCy multi-classification model (BERT integration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476279/model-got-multiple-values-for-argument-nr-class-spacy-multi-classification/57476733#57476733) in which my problem partialy have beed resolved I wanted to share the issue which comes up after implementing the solution.

if I take out the `nr_class` argument, I get this error here:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,2) (1,5)
```

I actually thought this would happen because I didn't specify the nr_class
 argument. Is this correct?

one more time my code for the multi-class model:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_pytt_bertbaseuncased_lg')
textcat = nlp.create_pipe(
    'pytt_textcat',
    config={
        "nr_class":5,
        "exclusive_classes": True,
    }
)
nlp.add_pipe(textcat, last = True)

textcat.add_label("class1")
textcat.add_label("class2")
textcat.add_label("class3")
textcat.add_label("class4")
textcat.add_label("class5")
```

The code for the training is as follows and is based on the example from here(https://pypi.org/project/spacy-pytorch-transformers/):

```
def extract_cat(x):
    for key in x.keys():
        if x[key]:
            return key

# get names of other pipes to disable them during training
n_iter = 250 # number of epochs

train_data = list(zip(train_texts, [{"cats": cats} for cats in train_cats]))


dev_cats_single   = [extract_cat(x) for x in dev_cats]
train_cats_single = [extract_cat(x) for x in train_cats]
cats = list(set(train_cats_single))
recall = {}
for c in cats:
    if c is not None: 
        recall['dev_'+c] = []
        recall['train_'+c] = []



optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
batch_sizes = compounding(1.0, round(len(train_texts)/2), 1.001)

for i in range(n_iter):
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    losses = {}
    batches = minibatch(train_data, size=batch_sizes)
    for batch in batches:
        texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.2, losses=losses)
    print(i, losses)
```

So the structure of my data looks like this:

```
[('TEXT TEXT TEXT',
  {'cats': {'class1': False,
    'class2': False,
    'class3': False,
    'class4': True,
    'class5': False}}), ... ]
```

Comment: the `(1,2)` refer to the 2 classes of the "resumed" optimizer and  `(1,5)` refers to the 5 classes of your problem. When I came across the same problem, I could make  the code work by reducing my problem to a 2-class problem. This is, of course, not a solution..

Comment: I tracked it down and I think it was fixed a couple of days ago: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-pytorch-transformers/commit/1adeac6ecfb37372bb396947beaf2ad60da563ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Milla Well already commented the answer can be found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-pytorch-transformers/commit/1adeac6ecfb37372bb396947beaf2ad60da563ed) (the bug fix on github from @syllogism_)

Comment: The link is dead :(

Comment: @walnut_salami link still working